# Creating geometry object from two lat/long doubles in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, georss

I would like to get some places from DBPedia in certain area, and that would be easy if those points would had geometry property. However, all they have is `georss:point`. I have converted this to two doubles, but I cannot convert them to `geo:geometry` object that can be supplied to location filter.

The code I have thus far:

```
PREFIX  xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
SELECT  ?name
        ?abstract 
        ?ns 
        ?ew
WHERE
  {  ?m                               foaf:name  ?name
  .  ?m                            georss:point  ?coord
  .  ?m  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract>  ?abstract
  .  BIND( xsd:double(strbefore( ?coord, " " ))  AS  ?ns )
     BIND(  xsd:double(strafter( ?coord, " " ))  AS  ?ew )
     BIND(                  geo:Point(?ew, ?ns)  AS  ?geo ) # <-- I have problem with this
     FILTER (bif:st_intersects (?geo, bif:st_point(?geo), 10))
     FILTER (LANG(?abstract) = "en")
  }
```

If you know any way to convert those or other filtering method, please enlighten me. :)

Comment: Well, I hadn't found a solution to this problem _stricte_, but use other filtering method. As I use Google Maps, instead of radius I use getBounds() function and then substitute those values to `FILTER ( ?ns > **south** && ?ns < **north** && ?ew > **west** && ?ew < **east** )`

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information here to give you a simple and clear answer.

However, I think you may be able to figure it out from the examples in [the GEOSPARQL documentation](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtGeoSPARQLEnhancementDocs) for [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), the DBMS engine which hosts DBpedia.  There's [more here](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/sqlrefgeospatial.html).